# show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\left ( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{k}\right )^k}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

How can I show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\left ( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{k}\right )^k}$ [converges](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20as%20k%20%3D%201%20to%20infinity%20((1%2F2)%2B(1%2Fk))%5Ek) ? I really have no idea how to start.

Comment: For $k\geq 4$, $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{k}\leq\frac{3}{4}$.  Now, compare to a geometric series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that when $k\geq 4$, we know that $\frac{1}{k}\leq\frac{1}{4}$.  Therefore, 
$$
\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{k}\right)\leq\frac{3}{4}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=4}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k\leq \sum_{k=4}^\infty\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^k
$$
The RHS is a geometric series which converges since $\frac{3}{4}<1$.  Therefore, by the comparison test, the LHS converges.  Adding on the first few terms doesn't change convergence.

Comment: Why not use $k = 3$?

Comment: @Mr.Chip No reason, I just picked a value.

Comment: @DanAntonio's answer is simpler than mine, please take a look.

Answer (score 7):

Directly with the $\;n\,-$ th root test:

$$\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac12+\frac1n\right)^n}=\frac12+\frac1n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac12<1$$

and thus the series converges.